# How to show items (articles, post, whatever) grouped by day? Example: like Poduct Hunt does with products on its daily leaderboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a lits of items in my models that I would like to list grouped daily in home. How to show items (articles, post, whatever) grouped by day? Example: like Poduct Hunt does with products on its daily leaderboard

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your result, creating a hash keyed by the `created_at` converted to a date:

```
hash = Article.all.each_with_object({}) {|e,h| ( h[e.created_at.strftime '%F'] ||= [] ) << e }
```

Answer (score 0):

Smathy's answer is correct. 
And if you prefer a higher-order, easier solution, you can try this gem: https://github.com/radar/by_star